# Filter array by axios get results

Tags: reactjs

I have images array that I get when the component load.
I try to filter images by title, so I get the title on the filterByTitle function.
I try to filter the images array by axios get results from flickr api.

```
filterByTitle = title => {
    let tempArr = [];
    this.state.images.map(image => {
      axios
        .get(
          `https://www.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.getInfo&api_key={some api key}&photo_id=${
          image.id}&format=json&nojsoncallback=1`)
        .then(result => {
          if (result.data.photo.title._content.indexOf(title) > -1) {
            tempArr.push(image);
          }
        });
    });

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({
        images: tempArr // update the images
      });
    }, 500);
  };
```

I succeed only when I use setTimeOut that wait for the map will end.

I expected to do the same without setTimeOut.
I want to setState only when the map will end.
How can I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Would this work out for you?   Also, the better solution would be to enclose title getting function in a promise and update state after promise gets resolved

```
filterByTitle = title => {
    let tempArr = [];
    let imagesLength = this.state.images.length;
    let processedLength = 0
    this.state.images.map(image => {
      axios
        .get(
          `https://www.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.getInfo&api_key={some api key}&photo_id=${
          image.id}&format=json&nojsoncallback=1`)
        .then(result => {
          processedLength++;
          if (result.data.photo.title._content.indexOf(title) > -1) {
            tempArr.push(image);
          }
          if(processesLength ==  imagesLength){
             this.setState({
               images: tempArr // update the images
             });
          }
        });
    });

  };
```

Comment: Its actually works!
but when there are no results, it shows me all the images again.
Do you know why?

Comment: The if condition isnt written to expect errors I guess,  if ( result.data.photo ).  so what if result is null?  JS will break

Answer (score 1):

You want to wait until all prosises are resolved, which is a use case for [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

It should look something like this:

```
    filterByTitle = title => {
    let tempArr = [];
    let promises = this.state.images.map(image => axios
      .get(
        `https://www.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.getInfo&api_key={some api key}&photo_id=${
        image.id}&format=json&nojsoncallback=1`)
      .then(result => {
        if (result.data.photo.title._content.indexOf(title) > -1) {
          tempArr.push(image);
        }
      });
    );

    Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
      this.setState({
        images: tempArr // update the images
      });   
    })
  };
```